# How do I add IP ranges in batch file after setting a command to set a IP Address

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ip-address

I've tried to use the set/p command to set the static IP address using the command below. But how do I include the add command which allows me to add multiple IP ranges in the Advance tab?

Meaning my static IP is `192.168.4.250`
but my IP range is `192.168.4.250 - 192.168.60.250`

```
@echo off
echo ipv4 set address "Ethernet 3"
echo ipv4 netsh interface name="Ethernet 3"
set/p address=First Address:
set/p mask=First Mask:
set/p gate=First Gate:
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %address% %mask% %gate%
```

which results in

[image]

Also, the IP Variable is the 3rd octet `192.168.%A.255` but I also wanna change the 1st and 2nd octet into a Variable, how do I do so if the command I use is `%A IN (120,1,130)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question,
but I'm 100% sure that my English is weak/poor, sorry...

Anyway, hope I'm not far from what would help you...

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo;iPv4 Set address "Ethernet 3" & echo;iPv4 netsh interface name="Ethernet 3"

:loop
cls & echo 

:: remove variable/value in using loop for command set "_var="
for %%i in ("address=", "mask=","gate=","dns1=","dns2=")do set "%%~i"

:: set variable/value in using loop for command to set /p "_var=Test to Screen" 
for %%i in ("address=First Address: ", "mask=First Mask: ","gate=First Gate: ","dns1=First DNS: ","dns2=Second DNS: "
     )do <con: set /p "_%%~i" || goto :loop

:: set variable/value in using loop for command set dns/ip 1st and 2nd
for %%i in (1.1.1.1,"1.0.0.1 index=2")do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 add dns %%~i

:: set variable/value in using loop for command set "Ethernet 3" static ip/mask/gate
%__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %_address% %_mask% %_gate%

rem For /L (1ST.IPV4.OCT.IP)do ...
for /L %%A in (198,1,200
    )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.128.60.255 %_mask% %_gate%

rem For /L (1ST.2ND.IPV4.OCT)do... and Set %%A.2ND.IPV4.OCT
for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130
     )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.%%~B.60.255 %_mask% %_gate%
        
rem For /L (1ST.2ND.3RD.OCT)do ... and Set %%A.%%B.%%C.OCT
for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130)do for /l %%C in (4,1,60
    )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.%%~B.%%~C.255 %_mask% %_gate% 

rem For /L (1ST.2ND.3RD.4TH)do ... and Set %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D
for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130)do for /l %%C in (4,1,60)do for /l %%D in (253,1,254
     )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.%%~B.%%~C.%%~D %_mask% %_gate%

endlocal & goto :eof || exit /b 0
```

---

- **Obs.:** I think the additional command would be useful to test connectivity with newly assigned ip, and exit the loop if it results in success:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo;iPv4 Set address "Ethernet 3" & echo;iPv4 Netsh Interface Name="Ethernet 3"

:loop
cls & echo; & for %%i in ("address=", "mask=","gate=","dns1=","dns2=")do set "%%~i"

for %%i in ("address=First Address: ", "mask=First Mask: ","gate=First Gate: ","dns1=First DNS: ","dns2=Second DNS: "
     )do <con: set /p "_%%~i" || goto :loop

for %%i in (1.1.1.1,"1.0.0.1 index=2")do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 add dns %%~i
%__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %_address% %_mask% %_gate%

for /L %%A in (198,1,200
    )do ;"%__AppDir__%netsh.exe" interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.128.60.255 %_mask% %_gate% && (
         <con: %__AppDir__%ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -f -4 -w 4|2>nul %__AppDir__%findstr.exe .*Received.=.[1-4].>nul && goto %:^)
        ) 

for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130
     )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.%%~B.60.255 %_mask% %_gate% && (
         <con: %__AppDir__%ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -f -4 -w 4|2>nul %__AppDir__%findstr.exe "Received.=.[1-4]">nul && goto %:^)
        )
        
for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130)do for /l %%C in (4,1,60
    )do %__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%~A.%%~B.%%~C.255 %_mask% %_gate% && (
         <con: %__AppDir__%ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -f -4 -w 4|2>nul %__AppDir__%findstr.exe "Received.=.[1-4]" >nul && goto %:^)
        )
        
for /L %%A in (198,1,200)do for /l %%B in (128,1,130)do for /l %%C in (4,1,60)do for /l %%D in (253,1,254
     )do ;%__AppDir__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet 3" static %%A.%%B.%%C.%%D %_mask% %_gate% && (
         <con: %__AppDir__%ping.exe 1.1.1.1 -f -4 -w 4|2>nul %__AppDir__%findstr.exe "Received.=.[1-4]">nul && goto %:^)
        )
%:^) 
:: Your next command came here...
endlocal & goto :eof || exit /b 0
```